# What is the use of ごと in this clause?

Tags: subordinate-clauses

This is the whole phrase and the sentence I don't understand is in bold:

> そして、コルド大王の息子で
>   悪の帝王と呼ばれるフリーザは
>   千年に一度あらわれるという
>   「超サイア人」のウワサを不快に思い、
>   サイア人を、 **彼らが住む惑星ベジータごと**、
>   宇宙から消滅させてしまうーーーー。

So "消滅させて" being passive and "サイア人" is the direct object, then "彼らが住む惑星ベジータごと" it's a clause that explain what the Sayajins are/were.  ごと could be a nominalizing suffix like:

> As to Furiza (...) the sayajins, they who living in the Vejita planet, were sadly extinguished from the universe (by Furiza?).

I don't undestand what they are using the dictionary form for 住む、 and if it's referring to "彼ら", the sayayins or modifying "惑星ベジータ", and i dont understand the use of ごと here.

Thanks form your help.

Comment: By the way, "消滅させて" is causative, not passive. And "〜てしまう" probably carries the sense of "do completely", and not "sadly/by mistake" here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

彼らが住む modifies 惑星, so 彼らが住む惑星 means "the planet they lived on." The suffix ごと means "as well as," "together with," "along with," or "and all" (as リンゴを皮ごと食べる – "eat an apple, peel and all"). Here, ごと is used to stress that this character "Freezer" didn't just destroy the Saiyan people, but their whole planet.